# how to compare Arraylist<hashmap<>>contents with json array

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I want to compare the contents of a Arraylist>getallAnimals() with a json array what i retrieved from the server.I am calling the Arraylist from the mainactivity . How can i do that? My code is below..

```
                          public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllAnimals() {
                  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
                  wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                   String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM animals";
                        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
                              Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                             if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                           do {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("animalId", cursor.getString(0));
                           map.put("animalName", cursor.getString(1));
                               wordList.add(map);
                                 } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                                   }

                                 // return contact list
                               return wordList;
                                         }
```

And my code for json is as follows:

```
                                //parse json data
                           try
                             {
                       JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                                String s,s1;
                                 Log.w("Lengh",""+jArray.length());
                                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){


                            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    s=json_data.getString("Animalname");
                                      //s1=json_data.getString("Type");

                                       Log.i("Animalname",s);
                                     // Log.i("typw",s1);




                                          }



                                         }
                             catch(JSONException e)
                                   {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail",            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) to parse your json. The JSONArray and JSONObject implement List and Map respectively so you can handle both data structures similarly for your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list). A lib to mapping json to object developed by Google.